# SapUI5: Why getting an error "Cannot read property 'setText' of null" on custom control

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to extend a MessageStrip control.

For starters, I've created a new file to extend it with no new params at all

MessageStrip.js

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/m/MessageStrip"],
    function (MessageStrip) {
    "use strict";
    return MessageStrip.extend("com.sap.it.cs.itsdpphome.controller.fragments.MessageStrip", {
        metadata: {
            properties: {
            },
            aggregations: {
            },
            events: {
            }
        },

        init: function () {
        },

        renderer:{}
    });
});
```

I've created also an xml file that retrieves a data from a model:

```
<List  items="{msgData>/msgData}" >
<CustomListItem>
    <wt:MessageStrip
        text="{msgData>Text}"
        type="{msgData>Type}"
        showIcon="true"
        showCloseButton="false"
        customIcon="{msgData>customIcon}"
        class="sapUiMediumMarginBottom">
        <Link text="{msgData>linkText}"
            target="{msgData>linkTarget}"
            href="{msgData>linkUrl}" />
    </wt:MessageStrip>
</CustomListItem>
</List>
```

I can get all model params in xml, except from "text" param!

If I remove `text="{msgData>Text}"`, then it displays all the correct params except from the text.

But when I add the `text="{msgData>Text}"`, then the console displays an 
error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setText' of null

[image]

Why is that happening?

Comment: if you reproduce this example in plunker, I can check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `init` of your base: `sap.m.MessageStrip` in your own `init` .

```
init: function () {
    MessageStrip.prototype.init.call(this);
},
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: Cool! working good, can you please let me know how can i figure this also?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937871/how-can-i-add-a-button-list-as-aggregation-to-custom-control

Comment: @Eli I will have a look